# My <script> is at the bottom of the page, but still runs first; how do I get the body to render before running the script?

Tags: javascript, html

We are often told to put the `<script/>` block at the bottom of an HTML page. I thought the reason for this was that the HTML renders serially, from top to bottom. So, that way, the script won't be run until after the page renders, and your user won't have to wait until it's finished.

However, that is not how the following page works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo Bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Foo Title</h1>
    <p>Bar Text</p>
    <script>
      alert("Hello world");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You have to dismiss the `alert` popup before you get to see the text on the page.

So apparently I was wrong. The HTML doesn't seem to be rendered or interpreted serially from top to bottom, if the script runs before the page renders. Why not?

Also how would I edit the above code so that the `alert` popup appears only *after* the text on the page renders?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Comment: Put it inside a window load event

Comment: @Lixus That's not the problem. I want the script to run after the rest of the body renders, not before. I know how to make it run before. I am wondering why, despite what tutorials have told me, this script appears to be running out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That way, the script won't be run until after the page renders

No. That way the script won't run until the DOM for the preceding content has been constructed. It is still possible for it to run before the browser has rendered the DOM.

> How would I edit the above code so that the alert popup appears only after the text on the page renders?

There isn't an explicit paint event that you can detect. You can delay it until the DOMReady event has fired, the load event has fired or a setTimeout has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello world");
    });
</script>
```

That will run when the page is fully loaded.
Have also a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: I'm sorry for being dense here, but I tried this, and it doesn't solve the problem. I was expecting to see "Foo Title" rendered on the page before the alert popped up, but after replacing `alert("Hello world");` with your code above, the page worked just the same as before.

Comment: @globewalldesk You might as well use JQery for that. I'll edit the answer and try again.

Comment: I appreciate it, but that doesn't seem to work either (in Windows Chrome).