# Why my website contents disappear till Prompt method finalized?

Tags: javascript, html

I have read that placing script tag at the bottom will solve such issue of disappearing contents of the webpage till JS runs but I am still facing such issue and I don't know what is the reason behind that?

[Example of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuZCS.jpg)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Script Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>First exercise</h1>
<p>Test 3 Built-in JS Methods</p>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS Code:

```
var firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
var lastName = prompt("What is your last name?");
var age = prompt("What is your age?");
var fullName = firstName +" " + lastName
console.log("Your full name is " + fullName);
console.log("You are " + age + " years old");
```

Comment: because prompt is blocking, if you do not want to have that, than you need to wait for the page to finish loading before calling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My <script> is at the bottom of the page, but still runs first; how do I get the body to render before running the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683948/my-script-is-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-but-still-runs-first-how-do-i-get-the)